How to solve the article service data in the database and cache inconsistent situation?

This is a simple architecture diagram of one of my article services. In general, the logic on the left is to update interactive information, and the logic on the right is to find interactive information.
Now the problem is, look at the following scenario:
If an article has just been published, now the first user clicks to see the details.
Enter the back-end logic, first look at the query on the right, at this time there is no data in the cache to check the database, the database does not (because the left execution is necessarily slower than the right, there is a timing difference). So my original design is to return err directly when I do not find the database query, which causes the user to receive err in this scenario, but in fact the user should see the read amount 1.
So I made the first change, in the right query database no data directly return a read volume 1, but do not insert the database, and write back to the cache 1, so after the change, the user does see read volume 1.
If you look at the logic on the left, and then above, the dao layer executes Upsert semantics, the database is 1 after execution, and the updated cache is 2. No problem now.
Then the second user also views the article, the same into the right logic, this time the cache has data 2, directly return, is also the user wants to see the number, and then look at the left logic to update the database 2, and then update the cache to 3. And so on, there is no problem.
However, the cache has an expiration time, the above will not be a problem is established before the second user to view the cache has not expired, if the cache fails, what is the situation?
Again, the first user has already checked, so the database is 1 and the cache is 2. Five minutes later, the cache expires. The second user then click to view the article: enter the right logic, cache no data, then query the database, return 1, write back cache 1; Go to the left, update the database to 2 and increment the cache to 2. The problem arises when the user expects to receive a read count of 2, but is returned with a read count of 1. And if the third user clicks to view before the cache expires, he sees that the number of reads in the cache is 2; If it is viewed after failure, the amount of reading he sees is also 2 in the database.
